# How can I parse a String to BigDecimal?

Tags: java, string, parsing, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I have this String: 10,692,467,440,017.120 (it's an amount).

I want to parse it to a BigDecimal. The problem is that I have tried both DecimalFormat and NumbeFormat in vain.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. We'll help

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this

```
// Create a DecimalFormat that fits your requirements
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
String pattern = "#,##0.0#";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

// parse the string
BigDecimal bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse("10,692,467,440,017.120");
System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

If you are building an application with I18N support you should use `DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale)`

Also keep in mind that `decimalFormat.parse` can throw a `ParseException` so you need to handle it (with try/catch) or throw it and let another part of your program handle it

Comment: If the grouping and decimal separator are switched the above code will not work. It will work if DecimalFormat is initialized as it follows `DecimalFormat res = new DecimalFormat(); res.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols); res.applyLocalizedPattern(formatter);`

Answer (score 27):

Try this

```
 String str="10,692,467,440,017.120".replaceAll(",","");
 BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal(str);
```

Answer (score 17):

Try the correct constructor
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

You can directly instanciate the BigDecimal with the String ;)

Example:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimalValue= new BigDecimal("0.5");
```

Comment: BigDecimal can not parse the example string.

Comment: It will fail for the string value: `1,000` commas are not taking care in construction conversion.

Answer (score 14):

BigDecimal offers a string constructor. You'll need to strip all commas from the number, via via an regex or `String filteredString=inString.replaceAll(",","")`.

You then simply call `BigDecimal myBigD=new BigDecimal(filteredString);`

You can also create a `NumberFormat` and call `setParseBigDecimal(true)`. Then `parse(` will give you a BigDecimal without worrying about manually formatting.