# Why does it keep rounding down to two cents on my java change/cashier program?

Tags: java, rounding

I have tried many ways like math.Round and making them doubles and ints but i have no idea why and where it rounds down to 2 cents at the end. When i purchase 32.27 and pay with 36 the answer is 3 dollars 2 quarters 2 dimes 2 cents. 
here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Change {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Purchase: ");
        double purchase = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Payment: ");
        double amountGiven = input.nextDouble();

        int remainingAmount = (int) ((amountGiven - purchase) * 100);


        int numOfDollars = remainingAmount / 100;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;

        int numOfQuarters = remainingAmount / 25;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;

        int numOfDimes = remainingAmount / 10;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;

        int numOfPennies = remainingAmount;

        System.out.println("Given $ " + amountGiven + " for a purchase of $ " +
                purchase + " we need " + numOfDollars + " dollars " + numOfQuarters +
                " quarters " + numOfDimes + " dimes " +
                numOfPennies + " cents ");
    }
}
```

Comment: First problem: you're using `double` to represent currency values. Don't do that. Use `BigDecimal`, or use a number of cents rather than dollars.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because the amount cannot be represented exactly as a double. When you convert to an int it gets truncated.

The change amount in cents is 372.99999999999955 if you print it with 14 decimals.

Either use `BigDecimal` or a custom `Currency` type that only uses `Integer` or `int` to do calculations.

Comment: I'm still learning how to code so I didn't know about BigDecimal. How do you implement the BigDecimal in the code?

Comment: you don't it is part of the standard library, do a moderate amount of research

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code, you'll see where your problem is:

```
final double purchase = 32.27;
System.out.println("Purchase: " + new BigDecimal(purchase));
final double diff = 36 - purchase;
System.out.println("Difference: " + new BigDecimal(diff));
System.out.println("Cent difference: " + (int)(100*diff));
```

The output will be

```
Purchase: 32.27000000000000312638803734444081783294677734375
Difference: 3.72999999999999687361196265555918216705322265625
Cent difference: 372
```

So you can see that your trouble starts right off the bat: the decimal value `32.27` is represented by the nearest `double` value, which is *slightly larger*. The difference is then *slightly less*, which after truncation drops a whole cent.

Lesson: don't parse the input into a `double`, but [into a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231802/how-can-i-parse-a-string-to-bigdecimal).

Answer (score 0):

Calculations of this type should *never* use primitive types. Always use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: It's also acceptable to use an `int` or `long` to represent the number of cents.

Comment: Not really, if you are planning to support multiple currencies, or things which are measured with several numbers after the comma, like exchange rates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can't do division that results in remainders on integer types without losing precision

```
double d1 = 32.27;
double d2 = 36;
int i1 = (int) (d1 * 100);
int i2 = (int) (d2 * 100);
int rad = (int) ((d1 - d2 ) * 100);
int rai = i1 - i2;
double rdd = (double)rai / 100; // <- this is what you are expecting
int ndi = rai / 100;            
//  ^ this is what you are getting 
//  int / int == double which gets silently truncated

System.out.println("i1 = " + i1);
System.out.println("i2 = " + i2);
System.out.println("rad = " + rad);
System.out.println("rai = " + rai);
System.out.println("rdd = " + rdd); // mostly accurate in this case
System.out.println("ndi = " + ndi); // truncated
```

#### Ouputs

```
i1 = 3227
i2 = 3600
rad = -372
rai = -373
rdd = -3.73
ndi = -3
```

Comment: Actually, I think integer division is the intended operation here (and works as intended).