# Hibernate: java.lang.String can not be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, casting

In database datatype of `empcode` is defined as decimal.

This code:

```
 public  KwlReturnObject getPayrollDataHrms(HashMap<String, Object> requestParams)
     {  

     boolean success = false;
        List lst = null;
        KwlReturnObject result = null;
        try {
            ArrayList name = null;
            String hql = "";
            ArrayList value = null;
            ArrayList orderby = null;
            ArrayList ordertype = null;
            String[] searchCol = null;
            if ((requestParams.containsKey("primary"))
                    && (((Boolean) requestParams.get("primary")).booleanValue())) {
                hql = "from PayrollDataDisp where empcode=?";
                String userid = requestParams.get("userid").toString();

                System.out.println("userid:"+userid);
                lst = HibernateUtil.executeQuery(this.hibernateTemplate, hql,
                        new Object[] { userid });

                if(lst!=null){
                result = new KwlReturnObject(success, "success", "", lst,
                        lst.size());
                }
                KwlReturnObject localKwlReturnObject1 = result;
                return result;
            }

            success = true;

        //  return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            success = false;

        //  return result;
        } finally {
        }
        return result;


 }
```

generates following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
    at org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType.set(BigDecimalType.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.param.PositionalParameterSpecification.bind(PositionalParameterSpecification.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at com.krawler.esp.hibernate.impl.HibernateUtil.executeQuery(HibernateUtil.java:421)
    at com.krawler.spring.hrms.common.hrmsCommonDAOImpl.getPayrollDataHrms(hrmsCommonDAOImpl.java:1744)
    at com.krawler.spring.hrms.common.hrmsCommonController.getPayrollData(hrmsCommonController.java:1686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.krawler.common.wrapper.generalController.getData(generalController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.krawler.esp.handlers.sessionAdvisor.invoke(sessionAdvisor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Show stacktrace and exactly what line of code.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: datatype of "what" is bigdecimal? Check your data types and their conversions. See if you're trying to map string to a bigdecimal somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
lst = HibernateUtil.executeQuery(this.hibernateTemplate, hql,
                    new Object[] { userid });
```

you are passing `userid` which is a `String` instance. Try to convert it to `BigDecimal`:

```
lst = HibernateUtil.executeQuery(this.hibernateTemplate, hql,
                    new Object[] { new BigDecimal(userid) });
```

You need to strip all commas from the number.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `userId` with a `requestParams.get()` as a `String` here:

```
String userid = requestParams.get("userid").toString();
```

And in the `executeQuery` the expected `userId` is of type `BigDecimal`, because as it appears it's the type of your `userId` in your entity, *which is very strange here because I don't see the use of `BigDecimal` for an `id`, `int` or `Integer` are more suitable types in the case of an `id`*.

So anyway the solution to avoid this Exception is to convert the `userId` to a `BigDecimal` with `new BigDecimal(userId.replaceAll(",",""))`, your code should be:

```
lst = HibernateUtil.executeQuery(this.hibernateTemplate, hql,
                new Object[] { new BigDecimal(userid.replaceAll(",","")) });
```

And keep in mind the importance of `.replaceAll(",","")` to avoid String format Exceptions, take a look at **[How can i parse a String to BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231802/how-can-i-parse-a-string-to-bigdecimal)** for further information.